# C# - Tuple arrays are mutable, but tuple lists are not. How do I get around this?

Tags: arrays, list, tuples, c#-7.0

I have an array of value pairs I want to modify. I need to add and remove values from this array as well, so I used a list. When I tried to use a list, I encountered an error.

`Error CS1612 - Cannot modify the return value of 'List<(int, float)>.this[int]' because it is not a variable`

So I decided I would investigate. I tried using an array instead, and it... worked fine? The following code only throws an error on `arr1[0].Item1 += 1;`.

```
static void Main()
    {
        List<(int, float)> arr1 = new List<(int, float)>() { (0, 0) };
        (int, float)[] arr2 = new (int, float)[1];

        arr1[0].Item1 += 1; // This line
        arr2[0].Item1 += 1;
    }
```

Why are tuple arrays mutable, but lists are not? Is this because arrays are simple blocks of data you can modify easily, but lists have a lot of backend behind them that complicates things? Is there a simple way to get around this, or am I going to have to make my own custom class?

Comment: C# arrays are special in that accessing elements in them gives you a *reference*  to that element, while the indexer of a `List` returns a copy

Comment: @UnholySheep: I would avoid using the term "reference" here - it's already an overloaded term, and "reference" to a value type ends up sounding a bit weird. I think it's clearer to think of an array as a collection of variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why are tuple arrays mutable, but lists are not?

The list itself is mutable, but not in the way you're doing it. Note that this isn't anything specific to tuples - it's just the case for *any* mutable struct.

The list indexer getter returns a *value* (i.e. a copy of the tuple in your case) - so modifying that value wouldn't modify the copy in the list. The compiler is trying to avoid you making a change to a value that's about to be thrown away. Array access *doesn't* do that - `arr2[0]` refers to the *variable* within the array. (An array is effectively a collection of variables.)

If you want to mutate the list, you can have to fetch the tuple, mutate it, then put it back:

```cs
var tuple = arr1[0];
tuple.Item1++;
arr1[0] = tuple;
```

Note that this also explains why you can't use list access expressions as arguments for `ref` parameters, but you can do the equivalent for arrays:

```cs
public void Method(ref int x) => x++;

public void CallMethod()
{
    var list = new List<int> { 0 };
    var array = new int[] { 0 };
    Method(ref list[0]); // Error
    Method(ref array[0]); // Valid
}
```

Comment: Most probably only because `ref returns` didn't exist in C# at the time `IList<T>` and `List<T>` were introduced. If they were, then there wouldn't be such difference, which now has to be kept forever for backward compatibility.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Hmm... maybe. `IReadOnlyList<T>` would *not* be able to use ref returns, which would introduce an odd inconsistency between those. (I suspect there are some more subtleties as well - when an array is copied due to list expansion, if you still had a `ref` to the "old" array, that could produce some really unexpected behavior. Basically I don't think it's a slam-dunk...)